# Python approximate group-by

Tags: python, python-itertools

I want to group the keys of a dict by their values. However, the values are only approximately equal. What's the best approach to doing a groupby in this scenario. I have:

```
buckets = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in my_dict.iteritems():
    closest = next((rep for rep in buckets if abs(rep - v) < 1e-3), None)
    if closest:
        buckets[closest].append(k)
    else:
        buckets[v].append(k)
```

Any itertools magic or other stuff that could simplify this/make it more pythonic, or is this the best I can do?

Comment: Since `buckets` is a dictionary, the results obtained can vary depending on which values happen to get seen first via the generator expression in the `next()` call.

Answer (score 3):

Your algorithm is `O(n**2)` since it is performing `O(n)` operations inside an `O(n)` loop:

```
for k, v in my_dict.iteritems():
    closest = next((rep for rep in buckets if abs(rep - v) < 1e-3), None)
```

You could make it `O(n log n)` by sorting `my_dict.items()` by values, and then looping over the sorted items. Notice that instead of `for rep in buckets`, if `buckets` is an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), you only have to look at the last bucket since the keys of `OrderedDict` will be in sorted order. So if the next value is close to any bucket, it has to be close to the last bucket. Thus, by using an `OrderedDict`, you do not need to loop over all the buckets. Just compare with the last one:

```
import random
random.seed(123)
N = 10
my_dict = dict(zip(range(N), [random.randint(0, 10)/10.0 for k in range(N)]))
print(my_dict)    
# {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.4, 3: 0.1, 4: 0.9, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.5, 7: 0.3, 8: 0.9, 9: 0.1}

import operator
import collections
items = sorted(my_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
buckets = collections.OrderedDict([(items[0][1], [items[0][0]])])
for k, v in items[1:]:
    last_val = next(reversed(buckets))
    closest = last_val if abs(last_val - v) < 1e-3 else v
    buckets.setdefault(closest, []).append(k) 

print(buckets)
```

prints

```
OrderedDict([(0.0, [0, 1, 5]), (0.1, [3, 9]), (0.3, [7]), (0.4, [2]), (0.5, [6]), (0.9, [4, 8])])
```

Comment: The values in the OP's `my_dict` appear to be floats, not integers.

Comment: I don't think that matters; the code will still work.

Comment: `abs(2.001-1.999)<1e-3` is False. So they should be in different buckets. But you are right -- the OP's code does clump them together...

Comment: You're right, sorry. So it seems the OP's code doesn't work properly.

Comment: The OP's code depends on the order over which the items in `my_dict` are iterated. Since dict items have no defined order (and may vary even from run-to-run in Python3), the code is non-deterministic.

Comment: That's what I meant in my comment posted under the question.

Comment: Anyway, good analysis and speed improvement. I realized the original was doing a linear search through the buckets each time, but hadn't worked out a fix by the time you posted with something that did -- so, I'll have to third that +1. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This would be a slightly more "pythonic":

```
buckets = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in my_dict.iteritems():
    try:
        closest = next((rep for rep in buckets if abs(rep - v) < 1e-3))
        buckets[closest].append(k)
    except StopIteration:
        buckets[v].append(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from your code being inefficient it doesn't guarantee same or any particular result each time since `.itetitems()` order could be arbitrary. To solve both of that you can simply use key function:

```
key = lambda x: round(x, 3)
```

And then you group the usual way, but using `key(v)` as index:

```
buckets = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in my_dict.iteritems():
    buckets[key(v)].append(k)
```